# Mercer's theorem eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I would like to get a confirmation if I understand well Mercer's theorem. I'm following the Wikipedia article about RKHS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space).

Let $X$ a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. You take a kernel $K:X \times X\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous, symmetric and positive semi-definite. Let $T_K$ the integral operator associated with $K$ defined in $L_2(X)$. We know from the spectral theorem that there is at most a countable decreasing sequence of eigenvalues of $T_K$ such that $\sigma_i \geq0 $ where $\lim\limits_{i\to+\infty}\sigma_i = 0$ with the eigenvectors associated. The eigenvectors $\{\phi_i\}$ form an orthonormal basis of $L_2(X)$. They are claming that as $T_K$ is positive, $\sigma_i > 0$. Does it mean that it is true only if $T_K$ is positive define ?

Comment: Doesn't $K\equiv 0$ satisfy your hypothesis?

Comment: Indeed. But I would like to know what results you lose when you only make the assumption that $K$ is continuous, symmetric and positive semi-definite.

Comment: $T_K$ is still compact and you can apply spectral theroem for compact self adjoit operators, But $K=0$ shows that there may be no positive eigen values.

Comment: Thank you. In this case, does it mean that the eigenvectors $\{\phi_i\}$ are still a basis of $L_2(X)$ ?

Comment: See Theorem 5.1 (and the comments after its statement) in Basic Opertor Theory by Gohberg and Goldberg. Mercer's Theorem is also discussed in this excellant book.

Comment: Thank you again. Last question, can we say that $H_K \subseteq L_2(X)$ ?  Can we have the equality ?